# Continuation passing transform

Tags: functional-programming, lisp, continuations

I'm stuck on something in in Shan's article *Shift to Control*, about CPS. On [page three](https://homes.luddy.indiana.edu/ccshan/recur/recur.pdf#page=3) he writes the CPS transform

```
x --> (lambda (c) (c x))

(lambda (x) E) --> (lambda (c) (c (lambda (x) E)))

(E1 E2) --> (lambda (c) (E1 (lambda (f) (E2 (lambda (x) ((f x) c))))))
```

Shouldn't the innermost expression on the third line be (c (f x)) instead? With c being the continuation applied to the value `f x`?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend trying a few examples for yourself to see how the transformation works.

Think of the CPS transformation this way:

- Results are passed to continuations.
- Continuations are passed to functions *as the last argument*.

Remember that in the application rule, `f` is a *CPS transformed* version of the lambda, not the lambda itself.

Consider transforming the identity function `(lambda (x) x)`. You get:

```
(lambda (c') (c' (lambda (x) (lambda (c) (c x)))))
```

I have renamed the continuation in the outer lambda to make things clear. I want you to notice what this part means:

```
(lambda (x) (lambda (c) (c x))
```

This is a function of two arguments, `x` and `c`, and it returns `(c x)`. The continuation is passed as the last argument. The effect is that a transformed lambda "swaps" the position of `x` with `c`.

When you use this function in an application, the continuation is passed as the *last* argument to the lambda, `((f x) c)`. It's not backwards, because the *transformed* lambda, `f` swaps them back into the correct order.